# How to extract all data in PHP OOP style which consists the result of executed query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am executing the following sql code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO order_shipping_addresses(user_customer_id, shipping_address_details, created, modified) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".serialize($address)."', '".$created."', '".$modified."')";
$connection = $this->establish_connection();
$data = $connection->query($query);
$order_shipping_address_id = last_insert_id();
$connection->close();
```

What i wanted was when this query is executed i wanted the row id in which this data is inserted, i am using the `last_insert_id()` function but i am getting an error of `Call to undefined method mysqli::lastInsertId()`

how to extract all the data from the `$data` variable and also the row id in which the data is inserted. I am using PHP OOP style.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: how do you declare this function `last_insert_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `$connection->insert_id`

Comment: worked perfectly thanks man :D